# Can Android Mobile App Close A USB Connection programmatically?

Tags: android

Is there any permission that would allow an Android App to close a USB connection? I am looking for any method that does not include firmware, rooting etc.  Is there someway to kill USB connections like adb connections from inside an app?  What permissions are required for this?  What API or broadcast can be issued to kill the adb connection? This might not require detecting specific connection or it might. Does anyone know a way to either stop any and all connections or an individual connection programatically? Thanks

A similar thing can be done to kill system dialogs:

```
 Intent closeDialog = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
 sendBroadcast(closeDialog);
```

How about adb/usb connections?

How about blocking such connections by creating a connection and keeping it open?

Comment: [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html) is what you are looking for.

Comment: I see some usb api in the docs but how would you kill an adb connection with this?

Comment: From the terminal, run the command adb kill-server

Comment: I want to do stop it from inside my app.  I want my app to disallow usb connections. A non system app cannot set usb debugging app programmatically so the only option is to try to kill the connection on detection or just periodically stop any connection found that's what I am looking for.

Comment: You cannot do it from android sdk

Comment: Why do you say that?